# Error aapt: Attribute "font" already defined with incompatible format. Original attribute defined here

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, aapt, build-tools

Following error message I get after updating supportlibs to 27.0.2 and compileVersion to 27

```
Error:(252, 5) Attribute "font" already defined with incompatible format.

> /home/ralfi/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.aar/644e31926a52609e6fffe47c9016abcc/res/values/values.xml
> Error:(252, 5) Attribute "font" already defined with incompatible
> format. Error:(252, 5) Original attribute defined here.
> /home/ralfi/ProjectFolder/android-example/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/internal/debug/values/values.xml
> Error:(631) Attribute "font" already defined with incompatible format.
> Error:(607) Original attribute defined here.
```

and this:

```
> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing
> process /opt/sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt with arguments {package -f
> --no-crunch -I /opt/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar -M /home/ralfi/ProjectFolder/android-example/build/intermediates/manifests/full/internal/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
> -S /home/ralfi/ProjectFolder/android-example/build/intermediates/res/merged/internal/debug
> -m -J /home/ralfi/ProjectFolder/android-example/build/generated/source/r/internal/debug
> -F /home/ralfi/ProjectFolder/android-example/build/intermediates/res/internal/debug/resources-internalDebug.ap_
> -D /home/ralfi/ProjectFolder/android-example/build/intermediates/multi-dex/internal/debug/manifest_keep.txt
> --custom-package com.example.android -0 apk -c de,en --output-text-symbols /home/ralfi/ProjectFolder/android-example/build/intermediates/symbols/internal/debug
> --no-version-vectors}
```

1. Also putting supportLibs back to 25 tell me the same error.
2. deleting build folders did not help

EDIT in my values/attrs.xml the name font related occurs only as following:

```
 <declare-styleable name="Styleable">
        <attr name="fontFace" format="string"/>
        <attr name="underlined" format="boolean"/>
        <attr name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier"/>
        <attr name="android:textSize"/>
 </declare-styleable>
```

and this tag:

```
<attr name="minFontSize" format="reference|dimension"/>
```

[Both Project and Module Gradle file](https://files.fm/u/ctdc28pp)

Comment: are you using a custom TextView or EditText?

Comment: It looks like font is a var that's declared twice (or more times) somewhere

Comment: Don't add the gradle files externally @RalfWickum. Add them directly into the question

Answer (score 1):

rename the type="font" in your Custom TextView class and change it to any other name say 
`<attr name="font" format="string" />` 
to
`<attr name="typefont" format="string" />`

and replace it in every xml file
`app:typefont="ProximaNova-Light.ttf"`

Comment: Where can I find the files to replace content with? I seafrched all /res and no "font" appear there

Comment: it will be attrs.xml

Answer (score 1):

In your `attrs.xml` find the below property

```
<attr name="font" format="string" />
```

and replace font to other name like `<attr name="font_name" format="string" />`

After that replace `app:font` to `app:font_name` in every xml file.

---

Why this error occurred?

After update android version nougat to oreo, there is on build functionality **Downloadable Fonts**

So that font already defined with an incompatible format.

For more information refer this link.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Please share your gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

There can be may few reasons why this happens. First one is that you defined your own font attribure. But according to the code you pasted that is not it.

Second one could be that you updated your dependencies. Since android gradle plugin does not correctly handle this scenario it could be that attribute is conflicting with old version of library. If that is the case `./gradlew clean` will resolve the issue.

Third option could be that one of your dependencies is defining font attribure. Are you including any other libraries that work with fonts?

Last option that I can remember is that some other library is importing different version of appcompat library. This is not likley but you can see thay by running `./gradlew :app:dependencies` in your terminal.

**EDIT**

aapt2 was introduced in lates versions of androud build system. Maybe that is the issue. You can dissable it by putting `android.enableAapt2=false` in to your `gradle.properties` file to verify if that is the issue.